# How to let webpack import bootstrap.css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have done, amoung others,

```
$ npm i jquery bootstrap --save
$ npm i webpack --save-dev
```

I have in src/main.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

This works. Somehow jquery.js is found in node_modules.
Can I do in the same way something like,

import _ from 'bootstrap.css';

? I do not know if it is of interest, but my webpack.config.js is,

```
module.exports={
    entry:'./src/main.js',
    output:{
        path:'./bin',
        filename:'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[{
            test:/\.js$/,
            include:/src/,
            loader:'babel-loader'
        },{
            test:/\.css$/,
            include:/src/,
            loader:'style!css'
        }]
    }
}
```

Maybe the include of the last loader is not OK. My project looks like,

```
[eric@almond getting_started]$ ls
bin  node_modules  package.json  public  server.js  src  webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Do you want to have your styles (with bootstrap) in bundle `.js` file or `.css` file?

Comment: @Everettss In the bundle .js file.